# Adding a text box dynamically if there is no value in the dropdown list using js/jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery. I was writing an application, in which user an option to choose his state from dropdown of 50 US states and after selecting a state he gets the respected counties dynamically in the dropdown as well. Suppose I want to dynamically insert a text box for people who donot belong to those 50 states and counties and want to enter their own state and county how can I do it using jquery/javascript? ( For example : If state not applicable please select "other" and enter your state and county)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following:

```
<select id="selectStates">
    <option value="01">Alabama</option>
    <!-- all other states -->
    <option value="51">Other</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#selectStates').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 51){
             $('<textarea />').attr(
                 {
                  'id':'otherState',
                  'name':'otherState'
             }).insertAfter($(this));
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q37X4/).

This should be enough to get you started, I think.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Comment: Thanks a lot David... This will definitely get me started.

Comment: Excellent! Obviously you're more than welcome to ask if you're having trouble. =)

Comment: I found a solution to this, as to deactivate the text box initially and if the user selects the "none" or "other" value in the dropdown, then he can enter in the text box. Simple and efficient!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bind a [change](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20change%20event&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/change/&ei=rsTSTuMpiMitB7L3iIwL&usg=AFQjCNG6_8Ux-oIrpspzZHMTf3NZ3-vxtw) event for the `select` element. 
Within that change event you could do something like this,

```
$('#selectElementId').change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue !== 'other'){//Change `other` with whatever value you put on the other option.
         //show the respected countries
    }
    else{
        var $div = $('<div/>');  //Creates a div
        var $label = $('<label/>'); //Creates label
        $label.html('Enter your state');
        var $input = $('<input/>', {id:'otherStateField', type:'text'}); //Creates a text input element with an ID-otherStateField
        $div.append($label).append($input); // Appends label & input field into the div
        $(this).after($div); // Appends the div after the select element
   }
```

And you can get the value of the text element using the `otherStateField` id.